# How to replace all occurrences of a string in a folder if that string is followed by another string, via command line

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed, command-line

I have a directory with a lot of HTML, and in that HTML are various anchor tags with different text that have the same href.

```
<a href="foo">First</a>
<a href="foo">Second</a>
<a href="foo">Third</a>
<a href="foo">Second</a>
```

How could I write a command to track down all "foo" strings in the folder that are followed by "Second" and rewrite foo?

The ideal output would then be

```
<a href="foo">First</a>
<a href="bar">Second</a>
<a href="foo">Third</a>
<a href="bar">Second</a>
```

So far I have come up with the following, but I don't know how to limit in in the way that I need. I'm using commas to avoid issues with "/" in the URL.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's,foo,bar,g' {} \;
```

Solutions without find/sed are also acceptable.

**EDIT** - my solution

After implementing part of @karakfa 's answer below I realized that I needed to also search up to(and exclude) the second part of the regex. Since in my real use case there were potentially other attributes in the anchor tag. After that I came up with this bit using perl rather than sed, since sed doesn't work with the non-include I used

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's%foo(?=.*Second)%bar%g' {} \;
```

Comment: It would be safer to actually parse the files with an HTML parser, then replace `@href` of `//a[@href="foo"][text()="Second"]` with `bar`.

Comment: @choroba I've never attempted that before, but a quick Google search shows some python libs that may do the trick.
What would you use specifically?

Answer (score 0):

you probably wouldn't want to replace all `foo`s.  A more restricted find/replace can be

```
  ... sed -r 's~(<a href=")foo(">Second</a>)~\1bar\2~'
```

Comment: Are you really going to suggest `sed` for html?

Comment: If you have text processing tool as your hammer, all the problems will look like nails. :)

Comment: you mean `... will look like plain text`. But that's not the case here.

Comment: The improved search did what I was looking for, although I made a jump to perl's find/replace in order to exclude what came after the string to be replaced. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction there @karakfa

Answer (score 0):

After implementing part of @karakfa 's answer I realized that I needed to also search up to(and exclude) the second part of the regex. Since in my real use case there were potentially other attributes in the anchor tag. After that I came up with this bit using perl rather than sed, since sed doesn't work with the non-include I used

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's%foo(?=.*Second)%bar%g' {} \;
```

Searches all files, find and replace on foo with bar, where second follows somewhere in the line.